# Magento 2: change template for block in "sales.email.order.renderers"

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, email-templates, layout-update

There is layout configuration file `module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_renderers.xml`:

`<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Creditmemo Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.renderers">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder" as="default" template="email/items/order/default.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>`

I need to change default template for block `Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder`. I have created own configuration update `.../view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_renderers.xml` in own module with:

`<referenceBlock name="default">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::email/items/order/default.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>`

but default template is used for the block as before.

Can I change template for block `Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder` using layout updates?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code that i use for override default renderer of email template.

Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder" />
</config>
```

Vendor/Module/Block/Order/Email/Items/Order/DefaultOrder.php

```
class DefaultOrder extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder
{
    public function setTemplate($template) {
        return parent::setTemplate('Vendor_Module::email/items/order/default.phtml');
    }
}
```

For override default.phtml file copy from `magento\module-sales\view\frontend\templates\email\items\order\default.phtml`
to your module
`Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml`

Answer (score 1):

You can just copy `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml` to `app/design/frontend/[VENDOR]/[THEME]/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml` and make your changes.

But you can also extend `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_renderers.xml` to `app/design/frontend/[VENDOR]/[THEME]/Magento_Sales/layout/sales_email_order_renderers.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Creditmemo Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.renderers">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder" as="default" template="email/items/order/default.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

And change whatever you need.